# How to fix read-only file-system on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mount, hard-drive, filesystem, fsck

Today, after several uninterrupted weeks of happily using my Ubuntu machine again, I ran into another error, this time just after okaying a typical software update.  Instead of giving me a successful package installation message, it gave me some sort of notification that "the daemon that allows installation is not working".  I can't remember if that was exactly it or not, but I hit "ok" and the box went away.  Strange I thought.

Suspecting something was up, I immediately hooked up my external drive to make a backup -- but my drive wouldn't mount.  It was visible in Nautilus, but when I clicked on it, it said: [image]

So apparently my file system has up and decided to go read-only. Is there a way to fix this, or must I purchase a new hard drive and start over?  Is there a way to somehow mount my external drive and backup my data first?  Can this somehow be fixed using `fsck`, a command I don't know about?

My system is set up with my `/` Ubuntu partition on a 250GB SSD, and my `/home` on a separate 500GB HDD.  I believe the problem must be with my `/` drive, since I can still edit and save anything in my home directory as normal.
I seem to be unable to edit anything on the `/` drive though, like install software or mount drives.
Here is a screenshot of the errors I got when trying to make a backup using Aptik: [image]

I'm still new to computers so am rather clueless here.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know there's a good answer out there, but I'm having trouble finding it right at the moment.

Your system has by default, a line in /etc/fstab which indicates that if there is an error in the file system, that it should go into read-only mode, to prevent further corruption or dataloss.

The way to fix this, is to boot from a live USB, open a terminal window and use the command

`sudo fsck -f /dev/sdxx`

where "sdxx" is the partition of the hard drive that Linux resides on.  You could use `lsblk` to determine the partition name, if you don't know it.

You *could* also copy your data to a backup hard drive before performing the disk check - the live USB should allow you to mount both your USB backup disk, and the partition that is having the problem (in read-only mode).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I will definitely try this as soon as possible.
One question though, since I like to know some of what a command does:  
What exactly is the purpose of the `-f` and what does it do?

Comment: ext4 writes data to the superblock on shutdown, and *may* erroneously write that the disk is OK.  the `-f` option informs `fsck` to check the disk, even if the superblock indicates that the disk is good.  `fsck` on an ext4 system will call `e2fsck`, so you can research the options with `man e2fsck`

Answer (score 17):

Go to the terminal and enter the following command and read-only problems in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will be gone:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/your_drive
```

Don't forget to unmount the read-only drives and restart Ubuntu.
Your drive addresses can be found by using:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Comment: This solution worked correctly for me.

Comment: This works for me, but there is no need to restart Ubuntu. Just remounting the drive is suffice.

Comment: Works also if ntfsfix gives error. The trick is to reboot and boot on Windows, that will check and correct his sh*t

Comment: similarly, this gave me an error but I was able to repair via Windows

Comment: `ntfsfix` is part of the `ntfs-3g` package. `sudo apt install ntfs-3g`

Answer (score 9):

Normally the mounted disk filesystem becomes read-only when the server or pc is not shutdown correctly. I had the same issue with my ubuntu server.
I ran the following command to run fsck and it fixed it.

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda1
```

You have to press y for everything and reboot after its done. and it works.

Comment: "You have to press y for everything and reboot after its done. and it works."

If you add "-y" to the command you will not have to press it for the possibly thousands of prompts

Answer (score 2):

Let the Computer shut properly, mine had taken around 15 minutes to properly shutdown after the read only file system error. Then use 
sudo fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda6
 and reboot. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue on a Vagrant VM.  A reboot fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was once able to backup my R/O HDD so you should be able to mount the disk on an **existing** mountpoint (ie, empty directory).

Otherwise:

1) the disk is remounted R/O because there is an error, if the error is temporary, rebooting the PC will reaccess the disk R/W (after a successful `fsck`).

2) if the error is permanent, you may still have R/O access to the disk, and can make a last backup by booting from a LiveUSB version.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use bootable image from within your operating system, creating operational media `/tmp/aptik` manually.
`/tmp/aptik/*****` may not be writable because of user permissions(there is a symlink `/root/.temp/aptik --> /tmp/atik`)

Then you just have to sudo it! =)