# Hardrive Failing

Tags: boot, hard-drive

Hello I apologize beforehand for any mistakes; I am new to this forum.

I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04.

I am having issues with my hard drive. Whenever I boot up my computer I have to manually `fsck` orphaned links every time ( I'm not exactly sure of the terminology. All I know is I have to type `fsck -fy /dev/sda1` every time I boot ). Once I boot up the computer I can open programs but after a period of time, I cannot open any new programs.

I cannot download/save files to my computer anymore, I just get the message "You are trying to save the file on a read-only disk. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again". This applies to system updates too. I cannot update software.

I ran a disk utility check and it said for overall assessment "Disk is OK, 3352 bad sectors". but I'm not so sure.

I'm pretty sure my hard drive is failing, but I wanted to get a second diagnosis from someone. I also wanted to ask how long I have before it fails completely?

Thank you!

Comment: If you have important data on that drive, it would be a good time to copy  to another drive(USB stick, external hard drive, etc).  You can then check out replacement hard drive or SSD to have on hand when that drive dies.  Can also read this link to try fixing read only error, but should get important data off that drive soon.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135389/how-to-fix-read-only-file-system-on-18-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hard drive should not have bad sectors. If it has - it's failing and I would replace it. Back up your data as soon as possible, because trusting on your disk to survive one more day is dangerous. (Though I probably will, there is no accurate way to tell how long it will keep working.)

If you want to have a second opinion on the state of your device, you could run a SMART self-test. This is [documented here](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/SMART_tests_with_smartctl) for example.

Comment: re: *"A hard drive should not have bad sectors."*... that's not correct. ALL **hard** disks have at least some bad sectors... but they're mapped out at the factory.