# Fix read-only partitions on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, fsck, read-only

Few of partitions in my file system have become read-only and I cannot create/copy any file to those partitions.

[@Charles Green](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135389/how-to-fix-read-only-file-system-on-18-04) says here to boot from a live USB and run the below command.

```
sudo fsck -f /dev/sda4
```

and this [source](https://linuxize.com/post/fsck-command-in-linux/) says to run below commands to repair corrupted file systems.

```
sudo umount /dev/sda4
sudo fsck -p /dev/sda4
sudo mount /dev/sda4
```

What could be the safest and easiest way to fix the issue?
My laptop is dual booted with Windows 10 & Ubuntu 18.04, filesystem type: fuse.

Comment: You adjust commands for your setup.  Most of us have a different partition file-system (those commands would need adjusting for my own system). Did you look at logs as to why the file-system was mounted RO?  You've provided no specifics as to what type of partition(s) you're talking about (what *file-system*?), nor release of Ubuntu

Comment: Updated the question based on your suggestions

Comment: To see your ext4 partitions that you can run fsck on: `sudo parted -l` Then adjust the fsck to use those partition(s).

Comment: Are the partition root or home?  Are they storage partitions mounted under media?  If they are mounted at boot under media then perhaps you can change fstab to mount them with open permissions.  Or just run a sudo chmod -r 775 /media/user/mountpoint

Comment: @walttheboss two of them are media partitions and the other one is the Windows partition

Answer (score 1):

I Rebooted the laptop with Windows and I could able to create new files in those read-only partitions.

Later I rebooted the laptop with Ubuntu and the issue was fixed, partitions were no longer read-only.

The partitions might have been corrupted due to improper shutting down of Windows. (Just rebooting with Ubuntu before rebooting with Windows, did not work for me.)

Comment: Always great when you followup with the fix.  Thanks for doing that.